# Transaction scope with pooling in Linq2Sql

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql, transactionscope

If I have pooling in the connection string set to true the following code works fine. If turned of it fails with: "MSDC is unavailable".

Is it just pure luck that both DataContext's picks the same connection from the pool when pooling is on or is there some kind of coordination done by the `TransactionScope`?

```
using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using(var db = new DataContext(connectionString))
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
    using(var db = new DataContext(connectionString))
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
    scope.Complete();
}
```

In my real code I can't currently pass a specific connection to the DataContext but have use the connection string. Also I would like to avoid using the Distributed Transaction Coordinator if possible.

Comment: Just what is the reason you are using two datacontexts of the the same type and the same connectionString? Why not simply use one Datacontext?

Comment: @Pleun A function in the Bussines Logic Layer is calling multiple functions in the Data Access Layer, each function with its own Data context creation.

Comment: So the first //Do stuff is DataAccessLayer function and and the second //Do stuff is the second function? Still they can use the same datacontext can't they?

Comment: @Pleun Thats correct. If they are going to use the same context, there needs to be some kind of life time management or synchronization on it, I cant just create it and put it in a variable in the DAL class since I cant be sure how long and by what other threads that is accessed currently.

Comment: Well, lifetime managment and datacontext do not go together. It should be logical unit of work and shortlived. You are doing winforms?

Comment: @Pleun no this is a web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting lucky here because both of your connection strings match, so you are getting the same pooled connection when pooling is enabled. However, the results will be undefined if there are multiple concurrent accesses to connections with this connection string, because you may not get the same pooled connection in the second DataContext instance.

If you have to create two DataContext objects within the same transaction, then you will need to use the DTC. If you can't use the DTC, then you'll need to find a way to use only one DataContext object within the transaction.

Comment: I _am_ using the same transaction for both DataContext's in my example and its working fine without DTC as long as pooling is on. But how can I be sure that the same connection is picked from the pool? Aren't there lots of connections (using the same connection string) in the pool or only one?

Comment: There will potentially be many connections with the same connection string in the pool. It is not possible to ensure that the same connection is picked from the pool if there can be multiple concurrent calls into this transaction.

Comment: Now, it would be possible to ensure that you get the same connection each time by limiting the size of the connection pool to 1, by adding "Max Pool Size=1" to your connection string. However, this will not scale well, and I wouldn't recommend doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would you suggest solving a problem like this? Explicitly sending in the same connection to the DataContext's ?

Comment: I would do that, or you could also try to refactor so that you only create one DataContext object, and then pass it around as needed.

Comment: "you may not get the same pooled connection": well, at least the initial connection cannot be returned to the pool while the transaction scope is open. After all, that connection will be needed to perform the commit or rollback. This has me thinking... Presuming the first connection is properly "closed" (from the coder's perspective), why would you ever get a different connection inside the same transaction scope? We know that the first one is still available (for the commit or rollback). Why would it give you a different one when you ask for the same connection string again?